# How to use trace in a code to show the interim results

Tags: haskell

```
import Debug.Trace

collatz 1 = 1
collatz n = if even n
              then  collatz (n `div` 2)
              else  collatz (3*n+1)
```

I have to use Trace and Show to see n's interim results but I really don't know how. It would be amazing if someone can help me debugging my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a line at the top of the definition as follows:

```
import Debug.Trace

collatz n | trace ("collatz called with " ++ show n) False = undefined
collatz 1 = 1
collatz n = if even n
              then  collatz (n `div` 2)
              else  collatz (3*n+1)
```

This technique (adding the first line above) is universal -- it works with any function definition, and does not require to touch the remaining code.

(Unrelated: I'd also recommend you also add a type signature for `collatz`. It's a good practice to do so before starting to write any function.)

Comment: I don't really understand why you use False = undefined, it's something like

Comment: @Tikotakatok `False` is used to avoid actually evaluating `undefined`. The whole line is equivalent to `collatz n | False = 1234`, except that it prints the debug info. Since the guard is false, `1234` will never be returned -- it is unreachable. Because of that, `undefined` is used instead of an arbitrary number to document that such case is indeed unreachable.

Comment: Thank you very much :))

Comment: Can I also use something like True = n?

Comment: @Tikotakatok If you use `True` the branch will be taken. That is, adding `collatz n | True = n` at the top will make `collatz` to always return `n`, and disregard the next lines, which become unreachable. If you add `trace` to that you will get debug info, but you are essentially modifying the semantics of the function, so that's a bad idea, in general. You can use `collatz n | False = n`, if you want, and still preserve the semantics.